# How can I execute a bash file (.sh) on PostgreSQL? On windows

Tags: windows, bash, postgresql, shell

I have a .sh file which can create a table and insert a data from a folder. How can I execute this file on a windows computer. I have already created the table using the pgAdmin3 of postgres as requested by the .sh file provider.

I am sorry for my English and description. I am new to SQL.

Comment: What exactly does this shell script do? Can you post the complete code?

Comment: what it does is create a table and then insert a data from a folder into the table. The data is placed on my desktop and there is a path to call that folder inside the bash file.

Comment: Can you extract those SQL statements? Or are they even stored in a separate SQL script and the bash script simply runs `psql -f setup.sql`?

Comment: I don't need to extract the SQL statements. can I run .sh file on windows?

Comment: No, you can not run a .sh file on windows (at least no easily), that's why you need to extract the SQL statements and run them through psql. Again: what exactly is the script doing? How is it passing the statements to psql? How does it call `psql`? Can you post the complete shell script?